# Why does Samsung not allow making more than 1 user?

Tags: adb, samsung, shell

I would like to add more users via pm on adb shell. Unfortunatly my S20 FE is set to only allow 1 user, 1 work profile and one secure folder user.
I tried to add more with pm add-user gab1 but it said ***"Error: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Cannot add user. Maximum user limit is reached. (code 6) Error: couldn't create User."***. I know that this worked back on Android 4 and 5 but then it also got limited by OEMs like Samsung.
Is there a way to add more users without rooting the phone?
I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
~> adb shell pm get-max-users
Maximum supported users: 1
```

I don't know specifically *why* Samsung does this but you can work around this restriction and have a secondary user by creating a *guest* user :

```
adb shell pm create-user --guest gab1
```

> **Guest user:** Temporary secondary user. Guest users have an explicit option to quickly delete the guest user when its usefulness is over. There can be only one guest user at a time.
> https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multi-user?hl=en